# Чи можна "розбити табір"?

Tags: вживання-слів

На сайті [української мови](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/antusurzhuk/posadutu-park) я знайшов картинку на якій вказувалося, що можна розбити ворога, серце, лоба, тощо. А на цьому [сайті](https://community.languagetool.org/rule/show/ROZBYVATY_NAMET?lang=uk-UA&subId=2) я знайшов інформацію, що також не можна казати "розбивати табір", натомість там були такі варіанти як "отаборитися", "стати табором". Однак, якщо ввести в гуглі цей вислів, то можна побачити, що він часто використовується не лише на різних сайтах, але й у перекладах книжок: "*Розбивати табір за всіма правилами не варто було на одну ніч, і мандрівники розташувалися просто на землі*" - "П'ятнацятирічний капітан" (із серії "Всеволод Нестайко рекомендує").

Отож, я звернувся до Академічного тлумачного словника і там також знайшов, що "розбивати" може означати "розташовувати, розміщувати, влаштовувати в певному місці що-небудь". Отже, виходить, що ми таки можемо вживати вислів "розбивати табір" у творах для ЗНО, перекладах, тощо? І чи можна на основі данного визначення із тлумачного словника сказати "розбити парк" замість "розташовувати парк" (наприклад у реченні "Влада пропонує розташувати цей Парк радянського періоду на території Гідропарку" - взято із [цього перекладу](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/indepth/story/2009/10/printable/091012_soviet_park_ak.shtml)).

Comment: Анатоліє, чи не могли б ви дати посилання на конкретний переклад "Пятнадцятирічного капітана", з якого ви навели цитату? Якщо це з фізичної книжки, то я прошу вас навести рік та перекладачку/перекладача. Я маю припущення, що, оскільки це не оригінальний твір українською мовою, а переклад із французької, то могла бути вжитою непитома для української мови конструкція, яка не була потім вичитана. Наперед вдячна!

Comment: Видатництво Країна мрій, 2010 рік, серія "Улюблені книжки" і перекладач Леся Борсук.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Коротка відповідь: можна! Але дуже залежить від табору.

Спочатку про види таборів. [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/tabir) подає наступні тлумачення цього слова:

> 1. Місце тимчасового розташування війська поза населеним пунктом. 
>      //  Укріплене місце тимчасового розташування козацького війська з обозом.
>      //  Військо, розташоване в такому місці.
>      //  (*перев. мн.*) Місце тимчасового розташування військових з'єднань для проходження тренувальних занять. 
>      **Табором стояти** (**ставати**, **стати**, **розташовуватися**, **розташуватися** і т. ін.): а) робити тимчасову зупинку в певному місці для відпочинку, ночівлі, підготовки до бою тощо (про військо). б) зупинятися просто неба для перепочинку, ночівлі тощо (про гурт людей).
> 2. Кілька або більше родин циган, що кочують разом, а також їх стан, обоз.
> 3. Місце тимчасового розташування великої групи людей; група людей, що перебуває в такому місці. 
>      //  Літня будівля, загін для худоби поблизу пасовищ, випасів. *— Так де, по-твоєму, краще **закладати літній табір для худоби**: на Данелевщині чи на Грузькій? — перевів розмову Дорош на господарські справи (Григорій Тютюнник, Вир, 1964, 172)*;
> 4. Місце, де перебувають військовополонені, в'язні.
> 5. *перен*. Суспільно-політичне угруповання; течія, напрям.

Тепер при вживання конструкції *разбить лагерь* у російській та варіантах перекладу українською всього виразу, а не кожного слова окремо. На агрегаторі словників [r2u.org.ua](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8C&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) можна знайти наступні варіанти:

> Російсько-український словник сталих виразів 1959р. (І. О. Вирган, М. М. Пилинська)
>
> - ***Разбить лагерь*** – табором стати; отаборитися.
>
> Російсько-український словник військової термінології 1928р. (С. та О. Якубські)
>
> - ***Разбивать***, **разбить** — розбива́ти, розби́ти; розміча́ти, розмі́тити; **Р. лагерь** — става́ти, ста́ти та́бором; Р. палатку — нап’я́сти наме́та; Р. позицию — розмі́тити пози́цію.
>
> Словарь росийсько-український 1893–1898рр. (М.Уманець, А.Спілка.)
>
> - ***Разбива́ть, разби́ть, ся*** =  3. розташо́вувати ся, розташува́ти ся. С. З. — Вози розташовані стоять. К. К. — Розташував ся з крамом — **Разби́ть ла́герь = та́бором ста́ти**.

Останній із цих словників (1800-х років той що) навіть наводить приклад із думи "[Хмельницький та Барабаш](http://www.ukrlib.com.ua/narod/printout.php?id=4&bookid=2)", де є такі слова:

> *На лядські табори наїжджайте, // Лядські **табори** на три часті **розбивайте**,*

Отже, табори таки можна розбиваюти, але не всі, і лише в контексті їх знищення.